# openni_node.launch not found

Tags: ros, openni-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS on my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit to work with RGBDSLAM. I followed all the instructions, installed ros-fuerte-openni-camera when it was not found. But after installing it, when I run `roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch`, I get the following error

```
while processing /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch'
```

Please help me.

With regards
Don

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39814/openni_node.launch-not-found/) by [DonaldV](https://answers.ros.org/users/2920/donaldv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch got deprecated with Fuerte. You'll have to do a bit of work to migrate. Take a look at the corresponding migration guide http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera_deprecated#Migration_guide.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-01**:
Note: there seems to be a bug in the launch script in the openni_camera_deprecated package. https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac/ticket/51